# How can you forward a client cert through a node.js proxy to a different backend?

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, vite, client-certificates

I can't find any documentation or results for how to do this, but our backend needs to read client cert data, but it has to pass through a NodeJS proxy.

I can set the NodeJS proxy to use Client Cert Authentication, and do some validation there, but the backend still needs the data from it and do additional validation; is there any way to forward the cert request?

The best thing I can think of is trying to find an event callback for the cert validation in Node, and then make a one-off request to the backend to trigger the cert request, but I'm not sure if that's possible either.